# How Stackoverflow Realtime Updates works?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Here is the screenshot taken from questions tagged with PHP.

[image]

So, If I open this page and leave it without refresh for some minutes it appers

`x questions with new activity`

And when I click it, It display all latest updates. I want to write similar script for news updates. Is it using JavaScript `setTimeout` to poll the server and embed the updates to `<div>`?

Comment: AJAX request and a timer.

Comment: Don't know why, but these `activity timers` stopped showing on my end. I thought this feature was removed.

Comment: Look at one of the page sources ;)

Comment: IMO this is better suited for meta.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: @elclanrs - pretty sure I read that its done using `websockets`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

websockets

```
StackExchange.realtime.init('ws://sockets.ny.stackexchange.com:80');
```

http://socket.io/

Comment: I appreciate that.  Would you say it is correct to say that COMET is capable of accomplishing what OP is asking about, even if it is not what is used by SO?

Comment: @DavidTansey Sorry, yes I'd definitely agree with that. They would both accomplish the same thing, they are just done in totally different ways :)